# What is the meaning of decode: could not decode JWT in playframework 2.6.x?

Tags: playframework

I am new to PlayFramework, and I am trying to implement a very basic login feature in Java:

```
session("connected",email);
```

Retrieval:

```
String user = session("connected");
```

However, whereas putting itens into session actually works (I print into console). When I try to retrieve it, it returns null, and I have the following exception:

```
[warn] p.a.m.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec - decode: could not decode JWT: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
        at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec$JWTFormatter.parse(Cookie.scala:652)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:577)
        at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.decode$(Cookie.scala:569)
        at play.api.mvc.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:742)
        at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.decode(Cookie.scala:728)
        at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.decode$(Cookie.scala:719)
        at play.api.mvc.DefaultSessionCookieBaker.decode(Session.scala:95)
```

What is the cause of this?

My application.conf

```
application.secret="I70pMkPNKJ5o6eq<I7:X@DF?evtvUQd7HSCn>I7mPHTt6fL8]HsFdNq5;DfH0JAo"

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=PostgreSQL"

ebean.default=["models.*"] 

play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
play.filters.headers.contentSecurityPolicy = null

application.mode=dev
```

My plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.2")
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `project/plugins.sbt`?

Comment: @Salem sure! I updated the original post.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too,

It happened while I was upgrading the Play framework and playing with filters at the same time.

What I did was

1. delete all cookies from the browser and restart it
2. restart the server
3. remove the session

   session().remove(XXX);
    or 
   Http.Context.current().session().clear();

and it stopped.

Comment: Unluckily, my browsers are configured to private mode, and I always close the broswer and restart the server between executions. I am struggling with this issue. It is very frustating, I am thinking about changing back to JSP/Struts :(

Comment: Hello, hmm, try to delete the session first as well Http.Context.current().session().clear(); and all cookies you previously set.

Comment: point 1 (do not forget to restart the browser) and point 2 was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just o register: I solved the problem downgrading to Play 2.4. Somehow, I believe that the Play 2.6's default security configurations led to problem.